# Can I cast view patterns on the data inside a data constructor?

Tags: haskell

I have a convoluted mess of data constructors in my code that I wanted to straighten somewhat with the help of that new `Pattern Synonyms` language extension. However, it appears to me that I can't do it without a specialized view function that strips the specific data constructor at hand, only to apply some usual library functions to the data inside. I would expect that I could pattern match against the constructor and then apply that usual library function as a view, getting rid of the need to explicitly define the specialized view function. Alas, I couldn't figure out how to do that.

The less obvious downside of writing a specialized view function is that, if it fails pattern matching, there will be an error that mentions the view function's name, thus foiling the abstraction of the pattern synonym. So I can't just have a pattern matching failure in my view function, but I rather have to explicitly return a Maybe value so that I can then fail to match a Just in the pattern itself. This is exactly boilerplate.

I will appreciate any comments on how best to arrange the code in such circumstances, including whether it's actually a good practice to put pattern synonyms to use this way.

This is the example code I put together specifically for this question, very similar to that which I actually have to write. I tried my best to be concise. I also put comments and examples everywhere -- I hope it helps the reader more than it annoys. You can also run the code in `ghci` at once.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    PatternSynonyms
  , ViewPatterns
  #-}

module PatternSynonym where


-- ### Type definitions.

-- | This wrapper may have been introduced to harden type safety, or define a
--   typeclass instance. Its actual purpose does not matter for us here.
newtype Wrapped a = Wrap { unWrap :: a } deriving (Eq, Show)

-- | This data type exemplifies a non-trivial collection of things.
data MaybeThings a = Some [a] | None deriving (Eq, Show)

-- | This type synonym exemplifies a non-trivial collection of things that are
--   additionally wrapped.
type MaybeWrappedThings a = MaybeThings (Wrapped a)


-- ### An example of what we may want to do with our types:

-- | This is a function that does useful work on plain (not Wrapped!) Ints.
doSomething :: [Int] -> [Int]
doSomething = filter even
-- ^
--   λ doSomething [2, 3, 5]
--   [2]

-- | This is the example data we may have.
example :: MaybeWrappedThings Int
example = Some [Wrap 2, Wrap 3, Wrap 5]

-- | This is a function that must only accept a collection of wrapped things,
--   but it has to unwrap them in order to do something useful.
getThings :: MaybeWrappedThings Int -> [Int]
getThings (Some wxs) = doSomething xs
  where xs = unWrap <$> wxs
getThings None       = [ ]
-- ^
--   λ getThings example
--   [2]


-- ### An example of how we may simplify the same logic with the help of
--   pattern synonyms.

-- | This helper function is necessary (?) in order for it to be possible to
--   define the pattern synonym.
unWrapAll :: MaybeWrappedThings a -> Maybe [a]
unWrapAll (Some wxs) = Just (unWrap <$> wxs)
unWrapAll None = Nothing

-- | This is the pattern synonym that allows us to somewhat simplify getThings.
pattern Some' :: [a] -> MaybeWrappedThings a
pattern Some' xs <- (unWrapAll -> Just xs)
  where Some' = Some . fmap Wrap

-- | This is how we may define our data with the pattern synonym.
--   It's got linearly less lexemes!
example' :: MaybeWrappedThings Int
example' = Some' [2, 3, 5]
-- ^
--   λ example == example'
--   True

-- | This is how our function may look with the pattern synonym.
getThings' :: MaybeWrappedThings Int -> [Int]
getThings' (Some' xs) = doSomething xs
getThings' None       = [ ]
-- ^
--   λ getThings' example'
--   [2]
--
--   λ getThings' example' == getThings example
--   True
```

Comment: I don't think there are better alternatives at the moment. I believe pattern synonyms are a great feature that should be used more, to separate the public interface from the underlying implementation. In my opinion, it's much better to export some useful patterns than exporting view functions and forcing the user to use view patterns everywhere (or defining their own pattern synonyms). Ideally, patsyms should be extended so to take both "in" and "out" parameters (I can't remember if Scala extractor objects already allow this.)

Comment: @chi It is unfortunate I can't accept a comment as an answer.

Comment: I'm cautious in turning my comment into an answer, since "I can't see a better way" is a pretty weak, opinionated answer (IMO). On several similar occasions I was (happily) proved wrong later, when someone else suggested an interesting approach in a proper answer. (Unrelated: removing a wrapper can now be done at _zero_ cost using safe coercions, which is better than the O(N) `fmap` approach)

Comment: @chi Is there something Haskell _cannot_ do? This `coerce` thing is incredible!

Comment: What do you think of this pattern: `Some' wxs <- Some (fmap unWrap -> wxs)`?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia @chi I think this: `pattern Some' xs <- Some (coerce -> xs)` -- is perfection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything Haskell *cannot* do?

I think this:

```
pattern Some' xs <- Some (coerce -> xs)
```

-- Is perfection.

Thanks to @chi for the `coerce` thing and to @li-yao-xia for the code that views the variable after matching with `Some` data constructor.

It's very intuitive, I just didn't even suspect Haskell can do this much.